# LINQPad error: Context is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad

I use `DbContext` from custom assembly. LINQPad fails to run any query with this error message:

```
'project.model.Context' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'project.model.Context' is less accessible than class 'UserQuery'
```

`Context` class was marked as `internal`, but making it `public` didn't solved the issue.

```
public partial class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("name=Context")
    {
    }

    // all constructors are public
```

Found [this](http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/7/objectcontext-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection-level), but it didn't helped either.

Comment: How are you connecting to the database with LinqPad? Does the database show on the left hand side under "Add Connection"?

Comment: @JonKittell, Yes, I used `Use a typed data context from your own assembly` and then `Entity Framework (DbContext)`.

Comment: Did you build the DLL in Debug Mode?

Comment: Also, the class is `partial`, maybe the other part is not public.

Comment: @JonKittell, It was in Debug Mode by default. I've tried switching to Release Mode and back, but it didn't helped.

Comment: @JonKittell, No, all parts of `Context` are `public`. It wouldn't compile with different access modifiers on `partial` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I was referencing wrong DLL file.

Switching `TypeAccess` in EDMX to `Public` (or just editing generated files) had helped.